# How to disable certain row in grid in ExtJS 4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I want to disable whole Row, all its text content, actioncolumns, editors etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

not really possible. I mean it's not in the framework. You can mark a record (=row) as disabled. You could add the functions setDisabled/getDisabled to the model of the store. Then you can call something like:

`grid.getStore().getAt(0).setDisabled(true)` for the first record

function for the model:

```
function setDisabled( state ){
    var me = this;
    me.disabled = state;
    me.fireEvent('disabled', state);
}

function getDisabled(){
    return this.disabled;
}
```

now you can listen for that event, get the disabled/enabled state. If it's disabled you could add a class to that row (`addRowCls( )` - `removeRowCls( )`) for the visuals. You can listen for the edit event. Then you can prevent editing when the record is disabled.

Not really an out of the box solution but use a little imagination and you'll get there! Hope it helps ;)